# Using special characters in a password validator

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to make a password validator and have run into a problem. It seems my code won't read special character. below is my code:

```
    <?php
        $Passwords = array(
        'Pas$word1',
        'Pas$word2',
        'Pas$word3',
        'Pas$word4',
        'pas$word1',
        'PAS$WORD1',
        'Password1',
        'Pas$word',
        'Pas$word 1',
        'Pas$word1234567890',
        'P$wd1');

        function validatePassword($Password)
        {
            if (preg_match("[^!-/0-9A-Za-z]", $Password)==1)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        foreach ($Passwords as $Password)
        {
            if (validatePassword($Password) == false)
            {
                echo "<p>The password <em>$Password</em> does not appear to be valid.</p>";
            }
        }
        echo "<p>Processing has completed.</p>";
    ?>
```

fixed my array so it has single quotes, everything is now displayed. Current problem is that everything is displayed. What is wrong in my validatePassword function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use single quotes or escape your literal dollar signs with backslashes. Otherwise, `$word1` will be interpreted as a variable named `word1`.

Comment: Why validate passwords at all?  Why not let users pick whatever they want for a password?  I think the most validation you should consider doing is minimum length.

Comment: FYI: Echoing a password back to the user is a *really* bad thing to do.  Ideally this validation logic should be preformed client-side and the actual valid password that's sent to the server should be *immediately* hashed when it gets there.  The validation can still be performed server-side for good measure, but don't echo it back.  Just highlight the input field as containing an invalid value (and provide some detail on why it's invalid, perhaps).  Then, of course, immediately hash the accepted password server-side.

Comment: @David, I realize this, I'm just following the rules for this assignment. It's more for learning than functionality right now.

Comment: @Brad I'm just following the rules of my assignment

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes or escape your literal dollar signs with backslashes. Otherwise, `$word1` will be interpreted as a variable named `word1`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.

Comment: I really don't get why people use `"` in php or Javascript instead of `'`. So many troubles would be solved this way. But you are correct, that will solve the issue. That or escaping the `$` (e.g.: `"Pas\$word1"`).

Comment: It's displaying correctly now, but what about allowing special characters to be used, right now every element in my array is being displayed, what did I do wrong in my validatePassword function?

Comment: See Sammitch's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem is that you do not have delimiters on your regular expression. Change:

```
if (preg_match("[^!-/0-9A-Za-z]", $Password)==1)
```

To:

```
if (preg_match("/[^!-/0-9A-Za-z]/", $Password)==1)
```

Your *third* problem is that you have error reporting turned down/off. Had it been on you would have gotten numerous warnings when running your code that would have indicated the source of your problems.

When you are developing new code put this at the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```